# Unable to close new WPF window until all UI threads are returned even if dispatcher priority is set to background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to WPF and making it up as I go along so apologies if I have done anything drastically wrong.

I have a main window that makes a new 'error window' once particular user controls have completed their business. This new error window returns a 'loading placeholder' to UI whilst a background thread is updating another part of the 'error window'.

```
        ErrorsWindow errorWindow = new ErrorsWindow();
        errorWindow.LoadingPlaceholder.Text = string.Format(@"Loading...
                                      Please wait {1} minutes and {0} seconds to see potential errors",
                                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorWindowWaitSeconds"],
                                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorWindowWaitMinutes"]);
        errorWindow.Show();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            errorWindow.SetupWindow();
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

So my errorWindow shows up in the UI with the loading placeholder text set correctly. The UI then waits 1 minute 30 seconds for the errorWindow.SetupWindow() method to complete. The issue is that during this wait period I cannot close the window until the errorWindow.SetupWindow() method has completed.
Is there a way to allow the window to close and just abort the background thread?

EDIT: I cannot use a backgroundworker or a task as I need to update the UI elements inside the errorWindow.SetupWindow() method

Thankyou in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question on another stackoverflow post here:

[How to make some Tasks change my WPF controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287010/how-to-make-some-tasks-change-my-wpf-controls)

It involves doing the long running task on another thread(using System.Task) then using the dispatcher on the separate thread to affect the UI thread with any UI related changes.

Answer (score 3):

Invoking anything on `Dispatcher` (if Dispatcher is of UI thread) **will run your delegate on UI thread only**. Hence, you can't close the window till UI thread is busy somewhere else.

Setting priority `DispatcherPriority.Background` won't make it run on background thread. It set's the delegate [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Background. It means that **all queued delegates on Dispatcher with priority higher than `Background` will run first before your delegate gets time to execute**.

In case you want to run your operation on background thread, use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

---

As per definition from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously at the specified
>   priority on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.

As stated above it runs delegate on associated thread of dispatcher. (which might be in your case is UI thread).

Comment: I have tried using a new thread and a backgroundworker but both throw an exception inside errorWindow.SetupWindow(); The exception thrown is 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' Dispathcher does not throw this exception which is why I have used it so far.

Comment: @Luke - That's because you might be trying to access UI stuff from background thread. That's called thread affinity. So, in my opinion if you have invoked something on UI thread, you should wait for it to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rohit. I can understand that I should wait for the UI thread in all other circumstances, with exception to mine. I only want the ability to close/minimise the window. Perhaps I can try to return the initial UI thread and then fire a subsequent event that does does my lengthy operation in a new UI thread. Thanks again